# Filter with map function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, purrr, tibble

I am trying to filter multiple columns (15) of a dataframe. specifically I want to remove the outliers using Q3 + IQR*1.5 and Q1 - IQR*1.5 method.

Toy example:

```
library(tidyverse)
aa <- c(2,3,4,3,2,2,1,6,5,4,3,1,15)
bb <- c(0.2,20,30,40,30,20,20,10,30,40,30,10,10)
cc <- c(-9,2,3,4,3,2,2,1,5,4,3,1,25)

df <- tibble(aa,bb,cc)
```

I tried without success:

```
i <- NULL
for(i in 1:ncol(fat)){
   po <- fat %>% 
     filter(.[[i]] >= (quantile(.[[i]], .25) - IQR(.[[i]]) * 1.5))
   
   po <- fat %>% 
     filter(.[[i]] <= (quantile(.[[i]], .75) + IQR(.[[i]]) * 1.5))
}
```

Can I use filter and map functions to do this? and how?

Many thanks
GS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `filter` with `if_all/across`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(if_all(where(is.numeric), ~ (.>= (quantile(., .25) - IQR(.) * 1.5 )) &
           (.<= (quantile(., .75) + IQR(.) * 1.5 ))))
```

Comment: Wow! It works, I was getting crazy...Super thanks.  Two further questions, what is doing the ~ there and if all the variables are numeric (as it is the case) can I omit where(is.numeric) ?

Comment: @gus079 regarding the `where(is.numeric)` it is selecting the numeric columns.  In your data all the columns are numeric.  So, you can either use that or `everything()` works as well or if you have selected columns, use `across(1:5, ` i.e. 1 trhough 5

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of base R option using `sapply`/`lapply`. We write a custom function to detect outliers and apply it to every column and select only the rows that have no outlier in them.

```
is_outlier <- function(x) {
  x <= (quantile(x, .25) - IQR(x) * 1.5) | x >= (quantile(x, .75) + IQR(x) * 1.5)
} 

df[!Reduce(`|`, lapply(df, is_outlier)), ]

#      aa    bb    cc
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     3    20     2
# 2     4    30     3
# 3     3    40     4
# 4     2    30     3
# 5     2    20     2
# 6     1    20     2
# 7     6    10     1
# 8     5    30     5
# 9     4    40     4
#10     3    30     3
#11     1    10     1
```

Using `sapply` -

```
df[rowSums(sapply(df, is_outlier)) == 0, ]
```